# Visual studio web api linq problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

i have a little problem with my controller. I have a database filled with players from fifa (Playersk as key,name and rating).
In my playercontroller.cs i can use

```
// GET: api/Player
        public IEnumerable<Player> Get( )
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            return db.Players;
        }
```

and

```
 //GET: api/Player/3
        public Player Get(int id)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            return db.Players.Where(x => x.Playersk == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

just fine by using http://localhost:63991/xyz.
However,i need to use their name and not their id. I'm stuck with this:

```
//GET: api/Player/Beckenbauer
        public Player Get(string playername)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            return db.Players.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(playername)).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

This gives me the same result as the first one,a json/xml(depends on my browser) with the complete table and not a filtered one.

What am i missing?

Comment: You may try by using `localhost:63991/api/player/yourplayername` or `localhost:63991/api/player?playername=yourplayername`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have only default route in your application with optional `id` parameter:

```
httpConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
)
```

Thus `id` is optional, this route is still selected when `id` doesn't present in the request. And your request with player name is mapped to `api/player` route which returns you all players.

You should create a route with `playername` parameter. The simplest way to do that is route attributes.

```
[Route("api/player/{playername}")]
public Player Get(string playername)
```

Don't forget to enable attributes configuration:

```
httpConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Note: returning the first player which contains given name `x.Name.Contains(playername)` will cause a problem for names which are contained in other names - e.g. `Herman` is contained in `Hermannsson`. Or even more - the player name is not unique thing and it cannot be used as the identity for the player entity. It's totally OK for two persons to have same names. So I believe `api/player/playername` endpoint should return a collection of players. Also by convention cotroller name should be in plural form: `api/players/42`.